# Is there a command to define a "virtual file" in a tex document

Tags: external-files

I wonder whether there is something like the `filecontents` environment, but without writing the actual data to the filesystem.

With the `filecontents` environment, I can write a texfile like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.tex}
Hello world!
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\input{myfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

This compiles nicely, but creates the file `myfile.tex` in the working directory. I wonder whether there is an alternative way to get the same compilation result, but without creating the file `myfile.tex` in the file system?

Alternatively, is there a command that I can put after the `\end{document}` to have `myfile.tex` removed?

Comment: In ConTeXt buffers do exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think luatex in principle allows you to use lua buffers in exactly the way you describe, but I don't know the details. If you do not have any verbatim material in the file you are writing out you can of course just use a macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mystuff{
Hello world!
}
\begin{document}
\mystuff
\end{document}
```

To remove a file at the end, if you execute latex with -enable-shell-escape you could use

```
\AtEndDocument{\write18{rm myfile.tex}}
```

or `del` or whatever command deletes files on your system, although it is probably just as easy to arrange the script or editor that is calling latex to simply clean up afterwards rather than rely on shell escape with latex.

Comment: I would use a `\long\def` so that he could use multi-paragraph definitions.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes or even `\newcommand` :-) (answer edited)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Doesn't apply here: it's _arguments_ that cannot be long with `\def`, not the replacement text itself.

Comment: Defining a new macro / command works actually well for my case, thanks for that :) Seems like I had an XY-Problem...

Comment: @JosephWright  Thanks.  Not sure why I thought that was the case, but I appreciate the correction.